# How can I determine the dependency of a Chocolatey package?

Tags: chocolatey

I keep getting the following error every time I run `choco upgrade all -y`. How can I determine which package depends on `vcredist2008`? (I didn't install it myself)

```
You have vcredist2008 v9.0.21022.8 installed. Version 9.0.30729.6161 is availabl
e based on your source(s).
vcredist2008 not upgraded. An error occurred during installation:
 Updating 'vcredist2008 9.0.21022.8' to 'vcredist2008 9.0.30729.6161' failed. Un
able to find a version of 'xnviewmp.install' that is compatible with 'vcredist20
08 9.0.30729.6161'.
The upgrade of vcredist2008 was NOT successful.
vcredist2008 not upgraded. An error occurred during installation:
 Updating 'vcredist2008 9.0.21022.8' to 'vcredist2008 9.0.30729.6161' failed. Un
able to find a version of 'xnviewmp.install' that is compatible with 'vcredist20
08 9.0.30729.6161'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the contents of the warning, I am going to say that it is this package, [xnviewmp.install](https://chocolatey.org/packages/xnviewmp.install).

If you look at that page, you will see that there is a hard requirement on version 9.0.21022.8 of vcredist2008, therefore the upgrade of it isn't allowed.